стартануть always = начать?
Is стартануть always possible as a replacement for начать or is it only found in some contexts? And is it only found in colloquial speech?
I found in at 07:35 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGBkYhTV29o

Стартануть is a perfective derivation of стартовать using the suffix -ануть.
This suffix denotes a one-time abrupt and energetic action: рвануть < рвать, долбануть < долбить, резануть < резать etc.
The loanword стартовать means "to start, to set off" in the context of a sports race, a trek, a tourist route, or any other motion along a predetermined path, that involves some physical fitness, effort, or determination, such as a ski descent that you see on the video.
By extension, this word also means "participate in a race" or "take off" (of a rocket, project etc.)


Стартовать на Тотьму и Устюг можно сразу у монастыря, за железнодорожным переездом. [Андрей Пермяков. Десятая часть года. Почти документальная повесть // «Волга», 2010]
По замыслу именно оттуда — с космодрома «Восточный» — станут стартовать российские пилотируемые корабли. [Вести из институтов, лабораторий, экспедиций // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]
— Буду стартовать всю брассовую программу — это дистанции 50, 100 и 200 м. Также, возможно, выступлю в комбинированной эстафете. [Олег Лисогор: «Что толку мечтать? Работать надо!» // «Известия», 2002.04.02]



its colloquial speech, def can be used when movement is implied.
IMO you could use it in all places instead of начать, e.g. "Я стартанул Коран/физиотерапию"  for "I started (reading) the Quran"/"I started (doing) physiotherapy". But some may sound weird to natives so be careful
I recommend using ru.wiktionary.org cuz its got jargon words like the one in that video explained pretty well.
